# Flask - 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I am working on my first Flask application. Taking some code directly out of [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/deferredcallbacks/#deferred-callbacks), I am trying to make sure that a value is present in the user's cookies.

```
def after_this_request(f):
    if not hasattr(g, 'after_request_callbacks'):
        g.after_request_callbacks = []
    g.after_request_callbacks.append(f)
    return f

@app.after_request
def call_after_request_callbacks(response):
    for callback in getattr(g, 'after_request_callbacks', ()):
        response = callback(response)
    return response

@app.before_request
def detect_unique_id():
    unique_id = request.cookies.get('unique_id')
    if unique_id is None:
        unique_id = generate_unique_id()
        @after_this_request
        def remember_unique_id(response):
            response.set_cookie('unique_id', unique_id)
    g.unique_id = unique_id
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/..../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/..../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1690, in wsgi_app
    return response(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I am trying to understand the reason for this error. Please help.

Comment: I encountered the same error when I forgot to return the rendered template, returning `None` instead, within the `dispatch_request` method of a Flask `View` subclass.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The issue

`remember_unique_id` does not return the response object, but `call_after_request_callbacks` assigns the result of calling each callback added via the `after_this_request` decorator to `result` and then returns it.  That is to say:

```
# This
for callback in getattr(g, 'after_request_callbacks', ()):
    response = callback(response)

# translates to this
for callback in [remember_unique_id]:
    response = callback(response)

# which translates to this
response = remember_unique_id(response)

# which translates to this
response = None
```

### The solution

Either:

- Update `remember_unique_id` to return the modified response object
- Update `call_after_request_callbacks` to check the returned object and make sure it is not None:

  ```
  for callback in getattr(g, 'after_request_callbacks', ()):
      result = callback(response)
      if result is not None:
          response = result
  ```

### Why does this happen?

Flask is a WSGI application under the covers and it expects `response` to be a WSGI application (that is, a callable object).  When it is handling responses from view templates it runs some checks to make sure that it is being something it can use as a response object and if the returned value is not a WSGI application it converts it to one.  It does *not* check that the response object hasn't been altered by the `after_request` decorators, and so when it tries to call the response object (which it assumes is a valid WSGI application at this point) you get the `TypeError`.

Comment: Thanks! That completely answers my question.